# Get the cumulative standard deviation (weekly) from the mean for test scores over a year period

Tags: sql-server, standard-deviation

As the title states, we have test scores for students across the year, and need to see how far from the mean the current average score is each week. Each average / deviation value should be inclusive for all the data before, so we would expect that the more data we collect for a single test, the smaller the deviation becomes over time.

This part retrieves the data into a tmp table so I can play with it, getting the score for each student:

```
declare @tab table(testid int, studentid varchar(20), score int, wk int)
insert @tab

select testid, studentid, sum(mark), datepart(yy, collected) + datepart(isoww, 
collected)  from MarksTable where testid = 12345
group by testid, studentid,  
datepart(yy, collected) + datepart(isoww, collected) 
order by   datepart(yy, collected) + datepart(isoww, collected)
```

So now that tmp table has testid, studentid, score and year+wk to give us a week value to group by, it looks like this:

```
12345   6423-96201  45  2022
12345   6423-96196  34  2022
12345   6421-96147  12  2022
12345   6423-96189  42  2023
12345   6423-96185  4   2023
```

(hundreds more)

I tried this:

```
SELECT wk,
STDEV(avg(score)) OVER (ORDER BY wk ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS StdDeviation FROM @tab t
GROUP BY t.wk
```

but that doesn't give me anything that makes sense.
e.g:

```
2022    NULL
2023    18.3847763108502
2031    22.1208800307161
2032    18.0739222823013
2033    18.2537667345674
2035    16.3268694692726
```

etc..

There's no way that can be correct.

What I need to see is the avg and deviation for each week, and these values need to include all the mark data for the weeks PRIOR to them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Stack is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU15) (KB4495257)
Running this in SQL Server Management Studio v17.4

Comment: Hard to play with this without test data and expected results. At a guess, it might be the interaction of the stdev and avg in the same over by. Perhaps write the averages out to a temp table and then do the stdev over the temp table?

Comment: I can get the averages per week easy enough, what I don't know how to do is get them cumulatively, so :

week 1 = week 1 -- 
week 2 = week 1 + week 2 -- 
week 3 = week 1 + week 2 + week 3 --